# string interning - should this code only create 10 strings in memory?

Tags: c#

Seems to create a lot more. Please advice why or how to intern correctly here.

Thanks

```
        IList<string> list = new List<string>(10000);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            {
                list.Add(string.Intern(k.ToString()));
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("intern Done");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 5):

It will create a lot more during the looping process (each iteration will generate a new string, then *replace* it with the interned value), but your resulting list should only have 10 unique references to the interned string values.

When you're completed, the interning table should contain the 10 strings (for values of k), as well as "intern Done", and any other literal strings in your app.

Answer (score 0):

According to intellisense, the (1000) is just the initial size of the list - probably increases performance (assuming you need all 1000!) to give it a size so that it doesn't have to create a new, single allocation in memory every time an item is added to the collection.

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't do a single allocation on each add. While I haven't run it through Reflector, I'd imagine it either adds half again as much space to double the current space every time its capacity is reached.

Comment: Also, this will have nothing to do with the number of generated strings, as each "doubling" will just copy the strings, by reference, into the new list.  The list just stores references to the strings themselves.